# KeyError with pagination in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I scrape a website with Scrapy that works well without pagination. When I use pagination, I have a KeyError.

Scrapy code:

```
class AnnonceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'rzc_results'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data_file = pkgutil.get_data(
            "rzc_spider", "json/input/complete_rzc_scrape_rectif.json")
        self.data = json.loads(data_file)

    def start_requests(self):
        for item in self.data:
            request = scrapy.Request(item['rzc_url'], callback=self.parse)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse(self, response):

        item = response.meta['item']
        item['results'] = []

        for caritem in response.css("div.adCardOuter_d2sn17 > div[itemprop='item']"):
            data = AnnonceItem()
            #model
            data["model"] = []
            data["model"] = caritem.css("h2.title_16j3u81 > div::text").extract_first()
            if len(data["model"]) == 0:
                data["model"] = None

            item['results'].append(data)

        yield item

        next_page = response.css(
            'a.link_huvdae-o_O-linkPrevNext_1v3fox8::attr(href)').extract_first() 
        if next_page is not None:
            url_pagination = 'https://www.url.com' + next_page
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url_pagination, callback=self.parse)
```

The error message:

```
File "/home/bolgi/anaconda3/envs/spiders/rzc_spider/rzc_spider/spiders/rzc_item.py", line 26, in parse
item = response.meta['item']
KeyError: 'item'
```

What is the problem and how can I resolve this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Request generated from the next page, you don't pass along the item in meta. If you change your last request to the following it should work:

```
meta = {'item': response.meta['item']}
yield scrapy.Request(url=url_pagination, callback=self.parse, meta=meta)
```

Comment: Indeed, was a problem in my original answer - should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are not sending `item` key in `meta` in this line

```
if next_page is not None:
    url_pagination = 'https://www.url.com' + next_page
    yield scrapy.Request(url=url_pagination, callback=self.parse)
```